# Why isn't this polymorphic?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        puts("A");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        puts("B");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof (b));
    (&a)->foo();
}
```

Comment: You know you're blowing the stack to smithereens should `B` ever be bigger than `A`?

Comment: This is UB, but if you were trying to figure out if how hard you can blow your own foot, try with an extra level of indirection: pass the modified `A` object to a function like: `void call( A& x ) { x.foo(); }`, since it is UB you might get anything at all, even `B` being printed... or a crash now or in production code, or... I don't believe in demons but *nasal demons*, those are real!

Comment: Undefined behavior explains everything.

Comment: This is almost more C than C++. Yes, there are classes, but cstdio and cstring? Why not use the C++ library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to mess with non-POD types like that. In particular, the C++ standard says that `memcpy`ing non-PODs results in undefined behavior, which, in your case, shows as continuing to see `a` as being of type `A`.

In your particular case, the compiler "knows" that the both the "static type" and the "dynamic type" of `a` is `A` (since its type can't "legally" change - your trick is illegal), so no virtual dispatch is performed, but `a.foo()` is called directly (and your trick of overwriting the vptr thus has no effect).

Answer (score 9):

Doing raw memory manipulation (such as `memcpy`) on [non-POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types invokes *undefined behaviour*.  You shouldn't do it!

Comment: (And, almost by extension, because there's _more to an object_ than the bytes that you can physically `memcpy`.)

Comment: @Tomalak: So is `sizeof(b)` not guaranteed to encapsulate *everything* related to the storage of `b`?  (Genuine question.)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: it encapsulates everything not indirectly referenced.

Comment: @Oli: Good question. I'm wondering whether the bytes under storage are guaranteed to encapsulate all the semantic information of the object. Consider the fact of the object's type, for starters.

Comment: My saying:  The size of a `struct` or `class` *may not* equal the sum of the size of the members.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're riding roughshod over any and all guarantees with your `memcpy`, and are lucky to get any behaviour at all. Use the assignment operator as you're supposed to!

Comment: Actually, the assignment operator wouldn't help here.  But at least the result would be well-defined.

Comment: roughshod ... that made me go to english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Because – why should it? The compiler sees that `a` isn’t a pointer or reference and therefore cannot call anything but the original implementation of `foo`. The compiler doesn’t bother to make the call virtual (because that is needlessly expensive).

As Oli said, your byte copy provokes undefined behaviour. Anything goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof (b));
(&a)->foo();
```

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is guaranteed to work only for [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)-types. So... UB is UB. No need to be surprised

Answer (score 0):

```
A a;
    B b;
    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof (b));
```

You will have an access violation in this code if A would have an members.
Right way is next:

```
A a;
B b;
A *c = &a;
c->foo(); //A::foo()
c = &b;
c->foo(); //B::foo()
```